# Замена подстроки во время загрузки файла

Tags: c++, html5, firefox, replace, substring

Есть проблема: во время передачи файлов по сети идет сбой, при этом js скрипты грузятся с ошибкой внутри скрипта. Природа сбоя пока не понятна. Требуется на конечной машине заменить несколько важных подстрок на лету в процессе загрузки. Например: sin30 бьется и грузится как cos30.(это просто пример). Соответственно скрипт не выполняется или выполняется криво. 
Пробую использовать FireFox на конечной машине и внести в исходник изменения что-то типа "str.replace(/cos/gi,'sin');" или "char* Replace(char* items, char* _cos, char* _sin)"в файле //source/xpcom/string/nsTSubstring.h  , на что компилятор, естественно, ругается. Вроде все на С++ написано, строку надо рассматривать как одноуровневый массив но не получается, да и сам файл до конца понять не могу. 
Кроме того в FF есть еще файлы отвечающие за загрузку: //source/parser/html/nsHtml5Tokenizer.cpp; //source/parser/html/nsHtml5Parser.cpp; //source/xpcom/string/nsTStringRepr.h; а может и еще какие?
Кто может подсказать где и в каком виде надо прописать замену подстроки, или в нескольких файлах, несколько раз?

Comment: "во время передачи файлов по сети идет сбой" - ну а при чем тут замена каких-то строк?

Comment: Складывается ощущение, что вы пытаетесь поставить костыль вместо того, чтобы разобраться в причине. Сегодня загрузился cos вместо sin, завтра что-то ещё. 

Попробуйте использовать защищённое соединение https или для теста передать данные по другому каналу связи - помнится, что некоторые провайдеры интернета были замечены во внедрении рекламного контента в траффик.

Comment: Вы из C++ перехватываете http траффик браузера и заменяете в js файлах контент?

Comment: Неясно, что вы имеете в виду, когда пишете: `на что компилятор, естественно, ругается` и `строку надо рассматривать как одноуровневый массив но не получается, да и сам файл до конца понять не могу`. Пожалуйста, раскройте эти два понятия подробнее

Comment: user7860670  - мне надо сделать временное решение

Comment: hwak  -  точно костыль, но получился замкнутый круг: ошибки выруливаю вручную, а искать причину некогда. Вот и надо время высвободить чтобы пока ошибки не искать в ручном режиме. Была такая мысль: про https, но как оказалось не в сети дело.

Comment: hwak - как временное решение хочу использовать FF. Там открытый код, но вот не могу с ним разобраться.

Comment: hwak - пробую внедрить replace внутрь FF, а потом собрать. Потому компилятор и ругается.